# Prompt user for TLS client certificate after already visiting the site?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to re-ask for a client TLS certificate after the user has already (recently) been on the site - without needing to clear history? Preferably with nginx.

The way nginx works with `ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca` is that after selecting none on first visit the browser remembers this, and doesn't ask again - event when the TCP (and thus TLS) connection is closed (one can force this with having no keep-alive, even for certain roots).

TLS renegotiation has been disabled in TLS.1.3, but [this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/TLS1.3#Renegotiation)  talks about `SSL_verify_client_post_handshake` - could this be utilized somehow?

Or is this a browser history thing? (i.e the web server might do whatever, and the browser would just continue with the choice made)

Workarounds that do work but are not ideal because the user can't just click a link:

- have the user restart the browser (or in the case of Firefox: clear "active logins" "clear recent history" popup);
- use different origins (i.e port or domain) for the "cert-less" and "cert-ful" sites;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive [`ssl_verify_client`](https://nginx.org/r/ssl_verify_client) can not be used at any lower level of the configuration than a  `server` block, so to have a different setting you will need to use a different `server` block, which also means a different hostname and/or port. So your only real solution is, as you said:

> use different origins (i.e port or domain) for the "cert-less" and "cert-ful" sites;

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it looks like canceling a previous choice made by the user in browser is not possible to force-forget from the server end.